# how to pass image to a web service in string format from xcode

Tags: webservice-client

```
 +(id)profilePictureUploadWebService :(NSString*)temp andimage:(NSString*)strimage
 {
//NSString *post=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_UserId=%@&_UserImage=%@",temp,strimage];
NSString *post=@"";
NSString    *urlTotal= [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mo.sale.com/as.asmx/SaveUserImage?_UserId=%@&_UserImage=%@",temp,strimage];
NSURL    *url= [ NSURL URLWithString:urlTotal];
NSLog(@"urlTotal is =%@",url);

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"data is =%@",data);
return (urlData);
}
```

Comment: What do you want, does the code given not work? Describe your problem, update your question.

Comment: thanks for reply, i was asking the better and fast way to upload image.